# Time series data preparation for LSTM classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I am trying to fit simple LSTM model to perform binary classification on multivariate time series data. I am confused with the time series data preparation steps to fed into the model. Most of the online materials covered data preparation for prediction(regression problem) using LSTM. For my case, I am trying to prepare data for classification using LSTM. How to make sure that I am not messing with the temporal sequence and class balance while performing train and test split?  My class labels are highly imbalanced. Is my code correct for LSTM classification? I appreciate your time. Thanks!

Sample data:

[image]

```
sequence_length = 10
def generate_data(X, y, sequence_length = 10, step = 1):
    X_local = []
    y_local = []
    for start in range(0, len(data) - sequence_length, step):
        end = start + sequence_length
        X_local.append(X[start:end])
        y_local.append(y[end-1])
    return np.array(X_local), np.array(y_local)

X_sequence, y = generate_data(data.loc[:, "V1":"V4"].values, data.Class)
```

Shape of the sequence:

```
X_sequence.shape, y.shape
((12237889, 10, 4), (12237889,))
```

Training and test data split:

```
training_size = int(len(X_sequence) * 0.7)
X_train, y_train = X_sequence[:training_size], y[:training_size]
X_test, y_test = X_sequence[training_size:], y[training_size:]
```

Shape of the training and test data:

```
X_train.shape, X_test.shape
((8566522, 10, 4), (3671367, 10, 4))
```

```
y_train.shape, y_test.shape
((8566522,), (3671367,))
```

Comment: As you have high class imbalance, the way you are splitting your data it's quite possible that all of your observations from low class end up in just one set i.e. either training/testing and you don't have any observations of that class in the other set. First, you need to make sure that 70 percent of each class lies in train and 30 percent of each class lies in test data.

Comment: Secondly you have to make 3D input of each class separately. Then separate out 70% and 30% of that class to make train and test sets for that class. Lastly combine train and test sets of all classes to make your final train and test sets.

Comment: @Muhammadhassan I had the same feeling, but how can I do that? I didn't find any single tutorials which discusses this issues.